# get data from JSON file into javaFX

Tags: json, javafx, fxml

I am working with javaFX and FXML and I need to get some informations stocked in a JSON file.
So I will read and write from the file.
Any solution?what to do?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: same thing with javaFX?!

Comment: @BenMustaphaSabrine Of course. Just because you are using the JavaFX library doesn't prevent you using any other Java libraries.